# Want to write a trace IP code in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps

I'm writing a program that shows on a google map with google api the locations of the ip address if possible, and I looking for code or directions on how to write the trace IP program in c#.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

IP doesn't give you a good idea about where a person is. For example anybody using AOL will have an IP in Seattle. But if that problem is ok for you, you can use [IP Address Locator](http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?getlocation). They have an API you can hook into.

Comment: Or ask the RIAA as they sue fax machines ;)